# Google Maps Direction Api Return wrong directions?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, map-directions

I got Response between two points from Directions API and parsed it and draw Polyline on the map but the problem is the line being draw over building

The code to draw the polyline:

```
 JSONArray steps = response.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");
                    PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                    for (int i = 0; i < steps.length(); i++) {


                        //add start_location
                        JSONObject stepS = steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("start_location");
                        rectOptions.add(new LatLng(stepS.getDouble("lat"), stepS.getDouble("lng")));

                        //add end location
                        JSONObject stepE = steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("end_location");
                        rectOptions.add(new LatLng(stepE.getDouble("lat"), stepE.getDouble("lng")));
```

[image]

**EDIT :** I found the solution

rectOptions.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points")));

Comment: Kindly post the solution as answer not on edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** : adding this line solved the problem

```
rectOptions.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(steps.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points")));
```